# Make some keywords not editable in content editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I added some `content for div in html`. And I made it as `contenteditable="true"`.

The content has some keywords like `[$FIRSTNAME$]`.

I want to make the keywords uneditable.

Please can any one help for fixing this problem?

Thanks..

Comment: can you check this and see if it is ok with you http://jsfiddle.net/8fqg4119/2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the editable content with span and set `contenteditable` attribute to that

```html
<div>
  <span contenteditable>fdfdfdfdf</span>
  [your keyword]
  <span contenteditable>fdfdfdfdf fdfdfdfdf</span>
</div>
```

Or wrap keyword by span, then you can avoid editable feature by setting `contenteditable=false`

```html
<div contenteditable>
  fdfdfdfdf
  <span contenteditable=false>[your keyword]</span>
  fdfdfdfdf fdfdfdfdf
</div>
```

**Update :** In the above method it can be removed by selecting whole string. So I should prefer first method

Comment: With the second method, you can still remove the keywords