# Make some keywords not removable in content editable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
span[contenteditable="false"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="editableDiv">
  Editable Span <span contenteditable="false">Not Editable Span</span> Editable Span
</div>
```

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32371343/make-some-keywords-not-editable-in-content-editable-div), I am able to make some keywords not editable in content editable. However, when I go on editable part of the span and I press `backspace` or `del` button, I can remove the not editable span. I tried with some JS but I did not succeed to make it work. So the question is different because I would like to avoid to be able to delete the not editable span

Answer (score 1):

I just found out there is `contenteditable` code. maybe what you mean is like this

```css
span[contenteditable="false"] {
  color: red;
}
span[contenteditable="true"] {
  outline: none
}
```

```html
<div id="editableDiv">
   <span contenteditable="true">Editable Span</span> 
   <span contenteditable="false">Not Editable Span</span>     
   <span contenteditable="true">Editable Span</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I though about this solution. But then it does not make the entire div looks like editable

Comment: i edited the `css` code. it looks pretty good. try to check again

Comment: Yes I will go to this direction thanks :)